# Pass data into dynamic AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's imagine we have a container into where we will add dynamic html (with `angular` directives)

```html
<div id="divContent"></div>
```

```js
document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = '<div id="divTest" ng-controller="TestCtrl">{{test}}</div>';
```

Here is the code of some dummy controller:

```js
angular.module("TestApp", []).controller("TestCtrl", function($scope)
                                                       {
                                                           $scope.test = "a";
                                                       });
```

To initialize `Angular` we will use `bootstrap`:

```js
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("divTest"), ["TestApp"]);
```

So question is how to pass `test` parameter that it's display `b` instead of `a`?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/disshishkov/Wjqup/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

```
$("#divContent").html(
      $compile(
        "<div id='divTest'>{{test}}</div>"
      )(scope)
);
```

But the above wont work because the controller is not available probably.

Do something like:

and inject $compile to your controller.